# Windows 7 backup error 0x81000037

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-7-backup

I had trouble backing up while repeatedly getting the error code 0x81000037. The microsoft kb acticles didn't help (nor applied to my situation).

After excluding some folders for backup I got rid of the error only to be left with a "file not found" error code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to download a repair program for my harddrive (in my case Seatools for DOS), running a long test and finally repairing bad sectors. Afterwards I could do a backup that included the folder causing 0x81000037 without the need to bother with reparse points and full antivirus scans. Now if I'd only known that at the beginning.